# Superslow wordpress running in docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I use official wordpress docker image with mariadb:

```
version: '3'
services:

  hlshop:
    container_name: hlshop_container
    image: "wordpress:latest"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    depends_on:
      - hlshopDB


  hlshopDB:
    container_name: hlshopDB_container
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./hlshop_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

php.ini:

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_vars = 3000
```

This runs on Ubuntu 18.04.
Problem is that page requests take too long: 5+ sec (time to first byte).

From logs I can see that there is cca 6s gap between GET request on "/" and the next request (request for the first image).

I have read about some problems with shared volumes, but this was mac specific.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question might be related to PHP and it's configuration rather than docker. I would suggest that you post your question to [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com) including your php.ini